# last: command not found after upgrading CentOS

Tags: centos, last

I upgrade CentOS from 7 to 8. There is no `last` command.

```
$ which last
/usr/bin/which: no last in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

I fail to install `last` with `dnf install`.

```
$ dnf install last
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
EPEL for redhat/centos 8 - x86_64                                                                                           0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'epel', ignoring this repo.
Last metadata expiration check: 20:42:39 ago on Sun 11 Apr 2021 05:40:02 PM CST.
No match for argument: last
Error: Unable to find a match: last
```

How do I install `last` tool?

Comment: Use `dnf provides */last` to find the package that contains `last`. Also correct your repo configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last` is not a separate package, but a command provided in package `util-linux`:

On a RHEL/CentOS 8 system that has the `last` command installed:

```
# rpm -qf /usr/bin/last
util-linux-2.32.1-24.el8.x86_64

# dnf provides /usr/bin/last
util-linux-2.32.1-24.el8.x86_64 : A collection of basic system utilities
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/last
```

The list of contents of the util-linux package can be viewed here: https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/util-linux-2.32.1-24.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

**If the upgrade of `util-linux` package has actually failed, then your system may be missing several very basic system commands and parts of PAM configuration.** If you have not yet rebooted after the upgrade, check the system for missing packages before rebooting.

You might try `dnf install @minimal-environment` to verify that all the essential system packages are present: the command should end without actually installing anything if none of the packages required for a minimal CentOS 8 installation is missing.

Note that there does not seem to be an "official" procedure for upgrading CentOS from 7 to 8, other than by a complete re-installation: all the available upgrade procedures are designed by third parties and not guaranteed to work in every possible circumstance.

Comment: thx so much. It did. Unofficial upgrading caused a lot of issues. `rpm -U util-linux-2.29-2.el7.x86_64.rpm` raised `error: Failed dependencies`. It might be better to re-install CentOS.

Comment: If you already upgraded the system to CentOS 8, why are you trying to upgrade/install a CentOS 7 `util-linux` package to it (as indicated by the **`.el7.`** in the package name)? But yes, reinstalling might be the best solution as the 7 -> 8 upgrade seems to be particularly tricky.

Comment: thx again. 403 Forbidden for [util-linux-2.32.1-27.el8.x86_64.rpm](https://koji.mbox.centos.org/pkgs/packages/util-linux/2.32.1/27.el8/x86_64/util-linux-2.32.1-27.el8.x86_64.rpm).

Comment: Finally, I found the available rpm, [http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/util-linux-2.32.1-27.el8.x86_64.rpm](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/util-linux-2.32.1-27.el8.x86_64.rpm).